# Search page with three types of search using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a search page that include three types of search that allow user to select one of these.

The second type contain a drop list that allow the user to select one of the values that are stored in the database.

- type 1 : by newest
- type 2 : by specialization
- type 3 : by name

Specialization Table :

- specialization _id
- specialization_name

Members Table:

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- specialization>>related to the specialization table by id

The first type works as it should, but the second type does not show the specialization related to the selected one but it shows all the users with their specializations.

I want to filter and show just the users that have the selected specialization.

Can anyone help me ??

## search.php

```
//************for specialization droplist***************************//
function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_id'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
$outputlist = "";
//**********search by new***************************************//
if(isset($_POST['searchbynew']))
{
    $listnew = $_POST['searchbynew'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE registered_date!='' ORDER BY registered_date DESC  ")or die((mysql_error("Error in quering new members List")));

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $row_id = $row['user_id'];
        $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
        $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
        $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
        $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];

         ////***********for the upload image*************************//
       $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
       $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
       if(file_exists($check_pic))
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }
       else
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }

        $outputlist.='
   <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="23%" rowspan="3"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                  <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                  <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                    <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  <hr />
          ';


    }//close while
}

if(isset($_POST['searchbyspec']))
{
    $selectedSpec = $_POST['specialization'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, specialization_name 
                        FROM members u INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                        ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id") or die(mysql_error("Error: quering thespecialization"));

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $row_id = $row['user_id'];
        $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
        $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
        $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
        $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
        $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];

        ////***********for the upload image*************************//
       $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
       $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
       if(file_exists($check_pic))
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }
       else
       {
           $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
       }

        $outputlist.='
   <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td width="23%" rowspan="3"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                  <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                  <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                    <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                   <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                   <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  <hr />
          ';


    }

}
?>
```